# How to validate the context ( this ) parameter?

Tags: javascript

I can easily validate that an array like object is passed as well as that a function is passed using the code below, commented as `validation here`.

```
$P.someKey = function (obj, func, con) {
    var key;

    // prevent type errors
    // must be !(null or undefined) and a function
    if (obj != null || typeof func !== 'function') {  // validation here
        return false;
    }
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            // if the function passes back a truthy value,
            // the loop will terminate
            if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

For consistency, is there a way to validate that a correct context value is passed in, or is this not needed as the the call() method will do this for me?

The more I think about is checking for `obj != null` ( which checks for null and undefined, the only two JS types that do not have properties ) is un-needed as well b.c. the `for in` statement will filter these out for me.

Comment: The for in statement will just do nothing if the object is null, so even that check might not be necessary.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mentioned in my question, what about the context property, what if I pass in something silly like `true`.  Too busy to write the test cases in a jsfiddle.net if someone wants to.